# Api городов и регионов

Tags: mysql, база-данных, api

Нужно в БД закачать две таблицы: 1 таблица с регионами , 2 таблица с городами. Сначала мне рекомендовали базу ФИАС, я ее скачал в виде  xml, в тех файлах что я просмотрел нет ни городов ни областей. Оставшиеся файлы он слишком большие их ничем открыть не получается. Потом наткнулся на api в контакте, но там вываливаются все населенные пункты без разбивки на города , села и т.п. а мне нужны только города.

Comment: Вам нужна таблица только ADDROBJ из ФИАС (только из полного не из обновления). Структура в описании форматов https://fias.nalog.ru/Updates.aspx

Comment: 2 гб весит, парсер php не может ее обработать, хотя я на выполнение скрипта больше 4 гб оперативной памяти выделил. Чем бы ее открыть можно было?

Comment: Видимо придется написать свой парсер, который будет считывать файл порциями